# Convert a string to a variable

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a CSV `data` with differents colnames. I would like to access a specific column, for this I am using `input`, here I request the name of the column in question.

```
name = input ("What is the name of the column")
data = pandas.read_csv(data, header=0,
new="data."+name
```

I know `new` is string but as I would make it a variable?. If name="abcd",  `new="data.abcd"`, but it isnt a variable, it's a string. I need a way to make it variable.

Comment: Just do `data[name]`

Comment: Yes, thank you. But I would like to know how to convert string to variable.

Comment: converting string to variable is not preferred. If you have to use string to keep value then put it in dictionary. `data = dict()`,  `data[string] = value`. It will be more useful if you want later use string to get value.